# Router unable to connect to internet

Tags: networking, dns, router, wireless-networking, isp

**Background** : My ISP has a web based authentication scheme . So when I first try to browse any site , it goes to the isp login page. Once logged in , further requests to web pages work fine . ISP has given me a static ip (192.168.58.150) which I configure in my ip settings of my laptop. The DNS & Gateway have to be configured to 192.168.58.1 .

**Problem** : If i connect the isp cable to my laptop ethernet port , everything works fine . But if it is connected to my wireless router , where I have configured the exact same settings(ip/gateway/dns etc) as I have done in my laptop , and if I try to access internet from my laptop , it doesnt work . My browser says "Resolving" and stays there , while it should take me to the isp login page . Why is this happening ? The most confusing part is that the settings are exactly the same in router and the laptop , while laptop works , router doesnt .

**Laptop** : Mac OS Mavericks

**Router** : NetGear Wireless

Comment: if the router web control panel shows Internet connectivity is OK (can you check this?), then you need to configure the laptop's gateway to be the router's LAN-side ip address

Comment: note that this is probably the wrong forum for this type of question, I guess "super user" is the right one

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ISPs that do things this way (both locking an IP to a MAC address and handing out private IPs instead of public IPs). You can probably clone your computer's MAC into your router (many routers have the option to manually enter the MAC it'll send out when ARPing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ISP is mapping your laptop's MAC address to the ISP's DHCP-supplied IP address you register with.  It's then (almost certainly) reconfiguring your connection onto a different VLAN (internal to the ISP) to get Internet access with that IP and MAC address combination.  To make this work through your router, you need to have that association made to your router's MAC address and that also means you must have NAT translation turned on for the internal LAN side for your laptop and other internal devices connect to that so the IP on your router is always used when your internal devices hit the ISP.  NAT on the LAN is usually, by default, turned on.  So make sure NAT is turned on and the router is getting a DHCP address upstream from your ISP, then connect through your router from the laptop (connected on one of the LAN ports) and register.

If that won't work for some reason, most routers have a configuration option to "pass-through" the MAC address of your laptop, or "first connected device", so you might want to try that if you can't get it working otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can give you a direct answer to your question, but there are a number of things you can check to figure out what the problem is.

Some routers have a diagnostics section. It might be helpful to see if you can use that to ping google.com from the router. I'm assuming you have some familiarity with the command line and that this is possible from your router.

It does sound like networking issues. If you need to login form your laptop then you would probably need to login from your router, but if that's not possible this may not work. If you can find the location that you setup your ISP information in the router there may be an option to add a user name and password.

In order to really get a solution you'll need to do some more data gathering.

I hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check DNS. Set router to fixed IP on WAN with the same configuration that your laptop gets when plugged in.